# Difference between 入って and 入りって?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Difference between 入って and 入りって ?

I imported a car from Japan some time ago, and when I turned on the ignition for the first time, the car started talking to me! I managed to translate the sentence using Google translate:

"Kado iritte kudasai"

kado - "card"
iritte - 入って - "go in"
kudasai - ください - "please give me"

I.e. "Please enter card". Makes sense.

However, entering "入って" gives the pronunciation as "haitte", which is not what I'm hearing from the device.

Why does "iritte" get transliterated to "入って",  which is then pronounced "haitte" (according to Google translate, at least)? I did somehow manage to get different kana for "iritte" as 入りって.

Comment: There is no verb いりる.  But if you don't know how to speak Japanese, I'm quite impressed with what you were able to figure out.  Bravo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be saying カードを[入]{い}れてください [kādo o irete kudasai]. The verb is [入]{い}れる [ireru], not [入]{はい}る [hairu]. The former is transitive and the latter is intransitive.

(*) 入りって makes no sense.